# Context dependent lexer

Tags: flex-lexer

I see the following in bash's `parse.y`. This means that the lexical analysis will be context dependent. How to use flex to do such kind of context depdendent analysis? Will this kind of context depdedent requirement make the flex code too messy? Thanks.

http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/parse.y#n3006

```
/* Handle special cases of token recognition:
  IN is recognized if the last token was WORD and the token
  before that was FOR or CASE or SELECT.

  DO is recognized if the last token was WORD and the token
  before that was FOR or SELECT.

  ESAC is recognized if the last token caused `esacs_needed_count'
  to be set

  `{' is recognized if the last token as WORD and the token
  before that was FUNCTION, or if we just parsed an arithmetic
  `for' command.

  `}' is recognized if there is an unclosed `{' present.

  `-p' is returned as TIMEOPT if the last read token was TIME.
  `--' is returned as TIMEIGN if the last read token was TIMEOPT.

  ']]' is returned as COND_END if the parser is currently parsing
  a conditional expression ((parser_state & PST_CONDEXPR) != 0)

  `time' is returned as TIME if and only if it is immediately
  preceded by one of `;', `\n', `||', `&&', or `&'.
*/
```

Answer (score 2):

(F)lex provides [start conditions](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Start-Conditions.html) to allow for context-dependent lexical analysis.

If you avoid the temptation to reproduce the parsing logic as a hand-written state machine in the lexical scanner, then start conditions can certainly simplify the implementation of context-dependent scanners.

For the particular application of conditionally-recognised keywords -- often called "semi-reserved words" -- context-dependent lexical analysis is often not the best solution. Instead, consider writing the scanner to always recognise the keywords and then add rules in the grammar to treat the words as identifiers in contexts in which the keyword is not possible. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31790483/1566221) for an example.